# How to implement form that requires users to validate email or phone number?

Tags: session, post, browser, get, user-experience

I'm trying to improve this form to make it a little more user friendly.

The main area I'm trying to improve is the validation process.

Right now, the form gets filled out on index page `/`, and the user is re-directed by the server to a `/validate` page. To improve the experience, the email or phone number is shown to the user so they can see whether they entered it correctly. (though rarely, it does happen)

I'm also not sure if the user should be given the opportunity to use another form of validation.

The one problem with the setup on the server side is storing the form information between page requests.

Currently I'm using the flash(one-time sessions) to store the email or the phone number. Once the user submits the form the session is lost.

I don't like using sessions for forms, because any time you have more than one window open (not that they should be in this case) the data can start to become unpredictable

I also don't want to use the url params for storing information, as this can have sensitive information being passed back and forth, and stored in browser history.

I was thinking I could do ajax, which I try not to use on sites facing a broad audience where someone is bound to be using an old version of IE.

The data I get from the form is stored in the database. I could use the GET method to store an id in params. If I use the id (or a random unique id) I run the risk of anyone guessing these ids and having access to other website users' email address and phone numbers.

I could also use a combination of the flash and hidden inputs with the unique id, but the danger of showing personal information is still there.

[image: mockup]

Comment: have you tried [html5 local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)?

Comment: No, I'm not too familiar with it, I try to stay away from html5 features without a fallback mostly because of older IE browsers. According to http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage it is supported down to IE8 so I may give that a try, however there is a known issues listed `The "storage" event is completely wrong in IE`

Comment: True. IE and html5 don't go that well together.